# How to convert Python 2.x to 3.x ADB

Tags: android, adb, qpython3

I would like to test my applications on real device through ADB. I've found the code but from Python 2.x. Could someone help me to make it work with Python 3.x?

I have Qpython3 on my smartphone, ADB in windows command list my phone as available device (I can reboot it), but I can't handle application test.

Code below should be at the beginning of the application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
ADB = r'D:\Programy\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe'
APPLICATION = 'test.py'
TARGET = '/storage/sdcard/qpython/scripts3/'
def main():
# Upload the application.
    subprocess.call([ADB, '-d', 'push', APPLICATION, TARGET + APPLICATION])
# Launch the application.
    subprocess.call('"%s" -d shell am start \
        -a com.googlecode.android_scripting.action.LAUNCH_BACKGROUND_SCRIPT \
        -n \
        com.googlecode.android_scripting/.activity.ScriptingLayerServiceLauncher \
        -e com.googlecode.android_scripting.extra.SCRIPT_PATH \
        "%s%s"' % (ADB, TARGET, APPLICATION))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`test.py` contains:

```
from android import Android
import sl4a
droid = Android ()

droid.vibrate(1000)
```

There was same topic here 7 months ago, but there's no answers to that. Thanks in advance!

EDIT1: I've changed -e to -d as I have real device - now the script transferred to phone, but it isn't starting by itself.

Comment: are you sure this is a python 2 vs 3 issue? the code you're showing should run (or not run) whatever python version. What is your problem exactly?

Comment: No, I'm not sure - I thought so.. It's just not working on the phone. I'm don't know what should I do to make it working.

Comment: you're executing this exact code on your phone?

Comment: No, I execute it on desktop in Visual Studio Code - that's the point. I want to develop code on desktop and load automatically to my phone by ADB, to see how it is working.

Comment: then you have to show us `test.py`. Please [edit] your question with the code.

Comment: I've edited it - just a simple vibrate of the smartphone.

Comment: at any rate, you should check the return call of `subprocess.call` to see if it worked. And maybe `sl4a` isn't known (although it doubt it...). Anyway thanks for the example, I'd like to use python on my Android device.

Comment: _It's just not working_... hmm. must be a python 2 vs 3 issue!

Comment: Code is from book with python 2.x so that's why I thought about it. You don't have to be rude.